# dat.gui custom css class

Tags: javascript, css, dat.gui

I've been trying to figure out a way to style individual panels or gui's using Dat.gui.

What is the best way to do this? I could search for panel names in the DOM then apply the style but it seems like an overly complicated solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of [this example](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui) you could use the CSS selector `.dg.main` to start, that is the panel container element.

You could use CSS to style the elements, or jQuery or similar to manipulate the DOM.